# Finding the property of a basis

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $V = P_2 [x]$, the vector space of polynomials of degree at most 2. Given that $\mathcal B \subset V$, I want to find whether the following is a basis, not linearly independent, not spanning, or neither linearly independent nor spanning.

> $\mathcal B = \{x + x^2 , 1 − x\}$

Although I understand the definition of all of the properties, I'm not sure how to approach such question to reach my final answer.

> Could someone please give me a step by step detailed guide on how to approach this question and other questions of this nature in general?

Thanks.

Comment: They are linearly independent because there is no way you can write $x+x^2=c(1-x)$ for $c\in \mathbb{C}$. I don't think it spans though; consider $p(x)=1$.

Comment: Since there are only 2 vectors in B, and V has dimension 3, B cannot be a spanning set for V.

Comment: @mathers101 The answer should be not spanning. I don't know how it's reached.

Comment: See the comment right above yours.

Comment: also, if you want to show that $V$ has dimension 3, just consider $B=\{1,x,x^2\}$. This is spanning and linearly independent, so it is a basis, and has cardinality 3. So $\dim(V)=3$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\mathcal B=\{v_1,\dotsc,v_k\}$ be a subset of a vector space $V$.

We say that $\mathcal B$ is *linearly independent* if the equation
$$
\lambda_1v_1+\dotsb+\lambda_kv_k=\vec 0
$$
can only be solved by $\lambda_1=\dotsb=\lambda_k=0$.

We say that $\mathcal B$ *spans* $V$ if for every $w\in V$ there exist scalars $\lambda_1,\dotsc,\lambda_k$ such that
$$
\lambda_1v_1+\dotsb+\lambda_kv_k=w
$$

In our case, $V=P_2(\Bbb R)$ and $\mathcal B=\{x+x^2,1-x\}$.

So, to check if $\mathcal B$ is linearly independent, suppose that
$$
\lambda_1(x+x^2)+\lambda_2(1-x)=\vec 0\tag{1}
$$
Collecting coefficients in (1) gives
$$
\lambda_1x^2+(\lambda_1-\lambda_2)x+\lambda_2=0\,x^2+0\,x+0
$$
Comparing the coefficient of $x^2$ gives $\lambda_1=0$ and comparing the constant coefficient gives $\lambda_2=0$. Hence $\mathcal B$ is linearly independent.

Can you check if $\mathcal B$ spans $P_2(\Bbb R)$?